# When I try to type in Visual Studio, it overwrites the next character

Tags: visual-studio

I am  using the latest version of vs 2019 community. I tried some of the solutions i found on internet but none worked. i tried `shift + insert key`, `insert key`, and clicking the buttons on the lower right of vs.

Here is a video of the error: https://gyazo.com/dee6f971e1191f2fab7fb340a2d85446

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Since I am using a laptop and the insert key is shrinked together with the delete key, it was preventing me from disabling OVR. I used On-Screen keyboard to disable it, by clicking Insert key.

Comment: Remember to accept your answer and mark the question as answered.